# How to raise errors based on condition

Tags: python

What is the best way to raise errors within python?

I was thinking:

```
if input = 14:
    raise valueError('error')
```

Thanks!!

Comment: other than the fact it should be `ValueError` (with a capital V), I'm not sure I understand what is your question - you seem to have your own solution

Comment: What exactly seems to be your problem here. What you've written seems to be already the answer.

Comment: afaik, you can only output one error message. You'll have to write a condition that checks everything, then chooses which error message to print. If you really want to print both, you'll have to do something like `ValueError('error'+'error1')` but that basically gives one error that is a string of both messages

Comment: You are already doing it. You're testing one condition (int type) and if it's not an int => raise error, otherwise you go onto the next condition (range). It's just some syntax stuff that's wrong, but sequentially your code is correct.

Answer (score 2):

It's fairly straightforward. You can use `isinstance(<value>,<type>)` to check for type and remember to change `valueError` to `ValueError`.

```
input = 0

if not isinstance(input,int):
    raise ValueError('error')
elif input < 5555 or input > 11111:
    raise ValueError('error1')
```

You can raise multiple exceptions by adding them into a list and raise it when it is not empty

```
input = 'g'

exceptions = []
if not isinstance(input,int):
    exceptions.append(ValueError('error'))
    exceptions.append(ValueError('error1'))
elif input < 5555 or input > 11111:
    exceptions.append(ValueError('error1'))

if exceptions != []:
    raise Exception(exceptions)
```

You can also make it more computationally efficient by using `try-exept` as suggested by @chepner

```
input = 'g'

exceptions = []

try:
    _ = int(input)
    if input < 5555 or input > 11111:
        exceptions.append(ValueError('error1'))
except ValueError:
    exceptions.append(ValueError('error'))
    exceptions.append(ValueError('error1'))

if exceptions != []:
    raise Exception(exceptions)
```

Comment: Use `is_instance` sparingly. It would be better to simply try to make `input` an `int`. If `int(input)` raises an error, either catch it and raise your own error or let the original error go uncaught.

Comment: @chepner You're right. `isinstance` performance is pretty bad. However, I usually prefer keeping the code short for less computationally expensive task so it is easier for OP to understand.

Comment: @jackiegirl89 you can pass the value errors into list and raise them whenenver they are not empty. I've updated the code so that it will raise multiple exceptions.